# Redirec da porta 443 para outra

Tags: htaccess

Pessoal veja se vocês conseguem me ajudar já pesquisei e não achei nada sobre isto.
É o seguinte eu tenho 2 domínios configurados para um site em laravel 7 até ai tudo bem. Configurei o htaccess da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio1.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

o dominio1.com.br é o principal e tenho o dominio2.com.br que redireciona para o principal so que quando eu digito https://dominio2.com.br ele não esta redirecionando para o dominio1. Mas se eu digito http://dominio2.com.br ele redireciona certinho para o dominio1.

O que se pode fazer para o https também ser redirecionado para o dominio1 quando digitado na url?

Obrigado